# Concatenate by row in a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a named range: call it range1. Thas has multiple columns & rows. Let's say it is 3x3.
I would like to generate, within a formula, a new range that is 3x1 - each row being the concatenation of the 3 columns in range1. Example:
Range1:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Blue | Monkey |
| Banana | Green | Bear |
| Grape | Yellow | Cat |

The formula should generate:

| D |
| --- |
| AppleBlueMonkey |
| BananaGreenBear |
| GrapeYellowCat |

The purpose of this is to compare range1 with a string such as 'AppleBlueMonkey'. The reason for this is that I wish to do something like an index(range1, range1=A1:C1), where A1, B1 & C1 are "Apple", "Blue", "Monkey". So far I am not coming up with a way to do this in one self-contained formula, without having to copy and write down the ranges over several rows & columns separately.

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate a bit on your original problem ("*I wish to do something like an index(range1, range1=A1:C1), where A1, B1 & C1 are "Apple", "Blue", "Monkey"*.") since it may be possible to achieve a solution without recourse to concatenation.

Comment: I agree with @JosWoolley. concatination is very simple thats not the problem. but what do you want to do with it show that. maybe we can provide you better solution then what you are thinking

Answer (score 2):

With Office 365 we can use BYROW:

```
=BYROW(range1,LAMBDA(z,CONCAT(z)))
```

[image]

But I would use TEXTJOIN instead to put something between the cells just so you know that you are matching on a true match:

```
=BYROW(range1,LAMBDA(z,TEXTJOIN("|",,z)))
```

Then your INDEX would be:

```
=INDEX(range1,MATCH(TEXTJOIN("|",,A1:C1),BYROW(range1,LAMBDA(z,TEXTJOIN("|",,z))),0),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(range1)))
```

Comment: I will always use the second approach, that is much helpful.

Comment: This looks really neat, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Although I am using some flavor of 365, neither the lambda function nor the byrow function show up in my application. I will have to look for another way.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ARRAYFORMULA function along with the & operator to concatenate the columns in each row of the named range range1.

Assuming that range1 is a named range that refers to the range A1:C3, you can use the following formula to generate the concatenated range:

=ARRAYFORMULA(range1&"")

This formula concatenates each row of the named range with an empty string, which has the effect of converting the columns to text and concatenating them together. The result is a 3x1 array with the concatenated values.

To use this concatenated range for lookup, you can use the MATCH function to find the position of the search string within the concatenated range. For example, if the search string is in cell A4, you can use the following formula:

=MATCH(A4,ARRAYFORMULA(range1&""),0)

This formula searches for the value in cell A4 within the concatenated range, and returns the row number where it is found.

Comment: ARRAYFORMULA does not exist in Excel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).